# Objects in Array, how can i access to them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
    var people = [
  { firstname : 'n1', lastname: 'ln1', age: 32, hasSmartphone: false }, 
  { firstname : 'n2', lastname: 'ln2', age: 40, hasSmartphone: true },
  { firstname : 'n3', lastname: 'ln3', age: 81, hasSmartphone: true },
  { firstname : 'n4', lastname: 'ln4', age: 40, hasSmartphone: false } 
                 ];
```

How can i get access to Objects in Array. I need access to firstName values ('n1' ... 'n4') and hasSmartphone values (true or false)? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<people.length;i++) {
  var person = people[i];
  var firstName=person.firstname;
  var sm = person.hasSmartphone;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples of accessing.

The first `firstName`:

```
people[0].firstName < the firstName property of this first object
      ^^
  first object
  in your array
```

Or `hasSmartphone` of the third object:

```
people[2].hasSmartphone < the hasSmartphone property of this third object
      ^^
  third object
  in your array
```